# Geo nodes | Capture attribute on Collection

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: Problem]

Is the way to capture and transfer attribute to collection?

I need values in nodetree transfer to Shader editor.

[image]
This is better view of my problem.

Comment: collection consists of instances, so you can just store attributes in them and use them in shader editor

Comment: This is not how Geometry Nodes work. Geometry Nodes is a modifier type, and this (and other) modifiers modify the data of an object. You can't modify something outside. What you can do is use an object wrapper, that loads the entire collection, assigns some attributes to instances of this collection, and outputs those instances to the Group Output, and then hide the collection.